# Unresolved external symbol __glewUseProgram

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am trying to build a game using C++, OpenGL and the libraries GLFW & GLEW.
I'm pretty confident that I have set it all up correctly, but I still get an error. I can use things like "glGetString" and nothing crashes, but when I try to use "glUseProgram(int)" I get the following build error:

```
LNK2001 - unresolved external symbol __glewUseProgram
LNK4272 - library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86' glew32s.lib
LNK1120 - 1 unresolved externals
```

The first line pretty much tells me that this is because of the GLEW-Library, sadly it seems I am the first on the Internet to have this problem because Google didn't help AT ALL.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

// Edit: It seems I cannot use any GLEW function although I have linked the glew32s.lib and defined GLEW_STATIC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the library is built for x64, but you're targeting the app for x86. I would resolve that issue first as that is probably the root cause of the unresolved external symbol.